# Angular Directive - Scope Breaks after adding directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am going through this tutorial.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-angularjs-directives--cms-22511

For some reason when I add my directive.

```
myPerfectDirective
```

It breaks the scoped variable that I have above it. My directive does not have a controller in it. Remove this from my html and my scoped variable returns.

```
  <my-perfect-directive></my-perfect-directive>
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ciderman/mfesvznv/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can't add both the `template` and `templateUrl` as properties in your directive. You could add one or the other, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g1wpLe4d/1/.